# In clojurescript, how would all protocols of an object be listed?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I have defined a function that lists the type

```
(defn js-type [o]
   (let [ty (type o)
        ty (if (and ty (.-cljs$lang$type ty))
             (.-cljs$lang$ctorStr ty)
            (js/goog.typeOf o))]
  ty))
```

usage

```
(js-type (keys {:a 1})) ;=> "cljs.core/KeySeq"
```

I would like to have a function in clojurescript that lists all the protocols

```
(js-protocols (keys {:a 1})) ;=> [Object, IMeta, IWithMeta .... INext ]
```

all protocols for KeySeq are here: https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/master/src/cljs/cljs/core.cljs#L5881-L5932

Answer (score 2):

This is yet another reflection facility that does not exist at runtime. You can get this information via a macro by looking at the contents of `cljs.analyzer/namespaces` or through the ClojureScript analyzer/compiler directly.